# What is meant by "Temperature response of a Light Emitting Diode"?

Tags: temperature, terminology, light-emitting-diodes

I'd like someone to clear up the meaning of '**Temperature response**' in the context of Light Emitting Diodes(**LEDs**) because I think I'm confusing it and **'effect of temperature**' on **LEDs**.

Comment: What is the context where this phrase was used? Both the I-V curve and the output spectrum of an LED (and probably the I-L curve as well) will change as its temperature changes. Which response is meant depends on context.